# Upgrading Umbraco 7: Replacing nuPicker with Contentment

Tags: c#, content-management-system, umbraco

In the process of rebuilding my umbraco 7 site in version 10, a major breaking change is the lack of support for nuPicker in v9+ (with the introduction of .NET core), I am hoping I can take the existing .config XMLs from nuPicker (in the uSycn folder) and run them through a script to transform them into something Contentment can pickup and populate without lose of functionality.

For context, I use nuPicker to add classifcations (used as tags) to content so that they can be linked to multiple subjects (often ones which cross over) for glossary type parent directories on my site.

Any advice or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at [uSyncMigrations](https://github.com/Jumoo/uSyncMigrations) as this package converts existing (legacy) properties and packages to alternatives.

You can find already a lot of nupicker datatypes will be migrated automagically in the source: https://github.com/Jumoo/uSyncMigrations/tree/main/uSync.Migrations/Migrators/Community/NuPickers